# Defining operators associated with a given HilbertSpace object in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I want to define operator objects in Sympy which are associated with different HilbertSpace objects. For example:

```py
import sympy.physics.quantum as smq

H1 = smq.HilbertSpace()
H2 = smq.HilbertSpace()

a1 = smq.HermitianOperator("a1")
a0 = smq.HermitianOperator("a0")
a1.hilbert_space = H1
a0.hilbert_space = H1

b1 = smq.HermitianOperator("b1")
b0 = smq.HermitianOperator("b0")
b0.hilbert_space = H2
b1.hilbert_space = H2
```

I want the operators `a0` to not commute with `a1`, but it should commute with `b1`. I saw that the operator has an attribute hilbert_space, but it does not seem to help. That is `a0*b1 - b1*a0` is not zero. This is very helpful, rather necessary for symbolic manipulation of operators in quantum mechanics. Is there a way to define operators belonging to separate Hilbert spaces?

Thanks